# In Java NIO, is a selector useful for a client SocketChannel?

Tags: java, css-selectors, nio

In Java NIO, it is easily understandable why a ServerSocketChannel must have a selector. The selector can check from among several client channels which is ready for I/O operations.

However, in some commentary I have read on the web, the selector mechanism is applied to the client SocketChannel. I don't understand why a selector is of use to a client. Can anyone explain why it is of use in the usual circumstance where there is only one server?

Comment: For example, http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/socket-channel.html at the bottom of the page makes the recommendation for selectors and SocketChannels.

Comment: But he doesn't recommend any of it for clients. There's a lot of bad advice in that tutorial: looping in non-blocking mode for example. Find a better one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless you're connecting to hundreds of servers, it is difficult to see the point of non-blocking NIO in a client at all. But if you're using non-blocking NIO, you definitely have to use a `Selector`, otherwise you can't know when to read the channel, or when it becomes writable again after an incomplete write.

Answer (score 6):

Selectors let you service concurrent communication across multiple channels using a single thread. It may be useful on a client when you must communicate with several servers concurrently, or when you communicate with peer computers in the role of a client, such as when reading a torrent.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would also like to contribute that Selectors for clients are apparently necessary for the mutual exchange of SelectionKeys between the client and server. Do you agree or disagree?

Comment: @Arvanem I wouldn't say that they are "necessary", because you can do the same thing using two threads. Yet selectors are are definitely convenient, letting you write a single-threaded code to address a concurrent task.

Comment: But it is necessary if your server socket channel is using a selector, right? Because there's no way apart from a selector that allows you to fire SelectionKey back to the server?

Comment: @Arvanem There is no such thing as 'mutual exchange of SelectionKeys between the client and server', or 'fir[ing] SelectionKeys back at the server'. These questions are meaningless. You don't have to use NIO at both ends of a TCP connection, if that's what you're obscurely getting at. TCP is TCP, however it is realized in the application.

Comment: @Arvanem EJP is absolutely right, you can implement the key exchange protocol regardless of the technology used on the other end. NIO's Select simplifies the implementation a lot, but you can implement the same protocol, say, with Java 1.2 on the other end, where NIO is not available, because it has not been introduced until 1.4.

Comment: *What* 'key exchange protocol'? What are we talking about now? What I said was that 'exchange of SelectionKeys' does not even exist. *Not* that it can be implemented.

Comment: @EJP I take on board your statement you don't have to use NIO at both ends of a TCP connection. So are you saying selectors and SelectionKeys operate internally and aren't transmitted externally? If that's the case why does server need to register OP_ACCEPT and client OP_CONNECT when initialized? Doesn't that imply some state communication between Selectors?

Comment: Ah, the penny is starting to drop. I will try a normal socket connection to a SSChannel and see if it works fine. Thanks for your response, sorry for being slow on the uptake

Comment: "Selectors and SelectionKeys operate internally". Correct. All that happens is that a Selector event is triggered by the read buffer becoming non-empty (including a FIN) or the write buffer becoming non-full. It has nothing to do with the network or the peer or the connection whatsoever.